# Content is not sitting below header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a div underneath my header that contains my main content but for some reason, the image of my logo causes the div to appear shifted to the right. I'm no expert at HTML/CSS and I feel dumb for not being able to figure it out.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing (Images substituted with flowers)

[image]

Code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
  font: normal 15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
}

a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
}

h2 {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 90%;
}

p {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 960px;
}


/* Header */

header {
  height: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

header h1 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}


/* About */

#about {
  padding-top: 1px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/16/48/f4/1648f4e01b50d7629559b12f42d6dbc6.jpg" alt="Logo" width="261" vspace="20"></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="about">
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg" width="500"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

It seems to work if I set my logo as the background of the header, but that sharply decreases its quality and I was hoping to later turn my logo into a link. I've searched far and wide for an answer here but nothing seems to be working. Any help is very very much appreciated.

Comment: You need to clear the floats in your `<header>`. The content in the body of your page is _"snagging"_ on the content in the `<header>`.

Comment: You have an extra closing div after the image tag in the "about" section.

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it and it looks great now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using floats to position your elements, you need to clear those floats in order for the content to appear where you want it to.  In the below I have added a clear to the about div as a simple demonstration:

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
  font: normal 15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
}

a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
}

h2 {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 90%;
}

p {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 960px;
}


/* Header */

header {
  height: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

header h1 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}


/* About */

#about {
  clear:both;
  padding-top: 1px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/16/48/f4/1648f4e01b50d7629559b12f42d6dbc6.jpg" alt="Logo" width="261" vspace="20"></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="about">
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg" width="500"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

There are many ways to clear floats - here are a couple of useful links about clearing floats:

- [The How and Why of Clearing Floats](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)
- [The Clearfix: Force an Element To Self-Clear its Children](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

I would recommend though that you move on from floats as with css3, there are now better ways to do layout - for example with `display:flex`

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floated elements in your `<header>` so the body of your page doesn't *"snag"* on it. You can use what is know as a *clearfix* to fix this.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
  font: normal 15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
}

a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
}

h2 {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 90%;
}

p {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

/* Header */

header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 960px;
  height: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

header h1 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: #444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}


/* About */

#about {
  padding-top: 1px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/16/48/f4/1648f4e01b50d7629559b12f42d6dbc6.jpg" alt="Logo" width="261" vspace="20"></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>

<main class="cf" id="about">
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg" width="500"></main>
```

If this is a new site I would recommend using `flexbox` instead of floats.

- `align-items: center;` will vertically center elements within `<header>`.
- `justify-content: space-between;` will push the `<h1>` to the left and the `<nav>` to the right.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
  font: normal 15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
}

a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  width: 960px;
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
}

header ul,
header li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

header nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/16/48/f4/1648f4e01b50d7629559b12f42d6dbc6.jpg" alt="Logo" width="261" vspace="20"></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>

<main class="cf" id="about">
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg" width="500"></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS cleaned up and navigation items positioned.
I eliminated the floats because I believe they should be avoided if possible. Floats do not follow the natural document flow.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
  font: normal 15px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
}

a:hover {
  color: #C0C0C0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper ul {
margin-left: auto;
}

.wrapper ul li {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
min-width: 70px;
}

/* Header */

header {
  height: 120px;
  width: 960px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

header ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}


/* About */

#about {
  padding: 1px 0 0 10px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/16/48/f4/1648f4e01b50d7629559b12f42d6dbc6.jpg" alt="Logo" width="100" vspace="20">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="about">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg" width="500"></div>
</div>
```